# jQuery drop down box close when new drop down is selected/ clean up jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have included a image of the issue that I am trying to resolve, and all of the code below.
I have questions about the code posted under the code itself (not in the script box).
Any help would be much appreciated.

**The HTML script**

```
<section id="s-explore">
    <div class="pagebreak">
        <span>The Lifestyle</span>
        <i class="down">&lt;</i>
    </div>
    <!-- Layout for Columns -->
    <div class="wrapper layout">
        <!-- Column Home 1 -->
        <div class="col">
            <div class="media">
                <img id="d1" src="images/main.png" width="318" height="269" alt="" />
                <div class="contenthover">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum pulvinar ante quis augue lobortis volutpat.</p>
                    <p><a href="#" id="dropbox1" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                    <h1></h1>
                    <h2><br /></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Home 2 -->
        <div class="col">
            <div class="media">
                <img id="d1" src="images/red.png" width="318" height="269" alt="" />
                <div class="contenthover">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum pulvinar ante quis augue lobortis volutpat.</p>
                    <p><a href="#" id="dropbox2" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <h1><a href="#"></a></h1>
                <h2><br></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Home 3 -->
        <div class="col">
            <div class="media">
                <img id="d1" src="images/car.png" width="318" height="269" alt="" />
                <div class="contenthover">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>

                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum pulvinar ante quis augue lobortis volutpat.</p>
                    <p><a href="#" id="dropbox3" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <h1><a href="news.html"></a></h1>
                <h2><br></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box1">
        <a href="#" class="close">[x]</a>
        <p>This is test box number one</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <a href="#" class="close">[x]</a>
        <p>This is test box number two</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
        <a href="#" class="close">[x]</a>
        <p>This is test box number three</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

**This is the jQuery script**

```
<!-- js hover over image -->    

<script>
   $(function(){
       $(' #d1').contenthover({
           overlay_width:300,
           overlay_height:150,
           effect:'slide',
           slide_direction:'bottom',
           overlay_x_position:'center',
           overlay_y_position:'bottom',
           overlay_background:'#000',
           overlay_opacity:0.8
      });   
   });
</script>

<!-- js for drop down box1 -->
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dropbox1").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#box1" ).slideToggle();
        });
        $("#box1 a").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#box1").slideUp();
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- js for drop down box2 -->    
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dropbox2").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#box2").slideToggle();
        });

        $("#box2 a").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#box2").slideUp();
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- js for drop down box3 -->
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dropbox3").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#box3").slideToggle();
        });

        $("#box3 a").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#box3").slideUp();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there anyway to clean up this jQuery code so that I do not have to have separate script for each drop down box?

Well I guess that I am not allowed to post images because I do not have a high enough rep here yet but maybe one day Ill be able to :)

Right now if you select all three drop down areas they just appear one after another, it would be nice if when one of the drop down boxes was selected, then the user moves on to any other button on the click of the second button the first drop down would close, and open the new box.

**This is the css script**

```
section .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
}
section .wrapper:after {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
}
section .wrapper.layout {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 95px 90px;
}
section .wrapper .fg {
    z-index: 200;
}
section .pagebreak {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 120px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #272727;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 300;
    zoom: 1;
}
section .pagebreak:after {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
}
section .pagebreak span {
    padding: 14px 14px 14px 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
section .pagebreak i {
    width: 16px;
    padding: 14px 14px 8px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px dotted #272727;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: 'dinliga-medium';
}
#s-explore {
    background: #fff;
}
#s-explore .wrapper .col {
    float: left;
    width: 318px;
    height: 269px;
    background: #000;
    margin-right: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
#s-explore .wrapper .col .media {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 318px;
    height: 269px;
}
#s-explore .wrapper .col .body {
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 477px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
#s-explore .wrapper .col .body.hover {
    top: 150px;
}
#s-explore .wrapper .col h1,
#s-explore .wrapper .col h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
#s-explore .wrapper .col h1 a:hover,
#s-explore .wrapper .col h2 a:hover {
    ![issue with the drop down][1]  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to iterate over your elements and set the bind event.

```
var elementCount = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < elementCount; i++){
    $("#dropbox" + i).bind('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#box" + i).slideToggle();
    });

    $("#box" + i + " a").bind('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#box" + i).slideUp();
    });
}
```

That should do it where **elementCount** is equal to however many dropdowns you have.

EDIT:

I should note that this isn't a very good programming practice to have dropbox1 and box1 unless the CSS stays the same. I would better to set a class and do this:

```
$('.class').bind('click', function(){
    preventDefault();
    var box = $(this).next('.box');
    box.slideToggle();
    box.find('a').bind('click', function(){
        preventDefault();
        box.slideUp();
    });
});
```

Now your HTML would need some slight modification though.

```
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="box">
    <a href="#">Text</a>
</div>
```

This method takes the item that is clicked and finds the immediately following box element, and then sets that binding.

Here are some references for you:

[$.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

[$.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: how does this code differentiate between the different drop down boxes?

Comment: My answer is entirely regarding the jQuery. So you'll still have different drop down box, but each will have 1 class. Then you bind based on that class. So you have one binding for all 3 drop downs.

Comment: I understand the concept that you are talking about, and will give it a try. Lets say that I did not care if all three drop down boxes could be displayed at once. Is there a way to include each id (box1,box2,box3) in one part of the jquery code that I have to limit the script that I already am using?

Comment: That's essentially what the for loop is doing. You could also build an array of boxes to iterate over. I made a fiddle of my thinking with the single bind. The for loop is requiring 3 separate binds.

http://jsfiddle.net/TBQa4/2/

Comment: Super sorry about that. http://jsfiddle.net/TBQa4/4/

using the slideUp() method on the class closes all of the elements, and then $(this).slideToggle() will toggle only that window. Sorry it wasn't working the first time.